# how to reload the parent window while closing popup window when on form submission i am using java class to show the child window content

Tags: java

```
function printPDF() {
var URL1= '<%=Handlers.getPath(PA.PDF_RH)%>';
var URL2 = "<%=jspBean.getPDFUrlContext()%>/" + 
                getValue(Obj.value, pdfFile);
            URL2 = URL2 + ".pdf";   
printFormat = window.open("","_blank","");
            printFormat.document.write("<html><head><title>Print Media Queue</title>");
            printFormat.document.write("<script> \n");
printFormat.document.write("function submit(){\n ");
printFormat.document.write("alert('Yeah ! I am inside submit');document.forms['myForm'].submit();\}");
            printFormat.document.write("function afterprint() { \n");
            printFormat.document.write("alert('i am inside After print method')\n");
            printFormat.document.write("self.close();\n");
            printFormat.document.write("opener.<%=jspBean.FORM_PRINT%>.submit();\n");
printFormat.document.write("} \n");
            printFormat.document.write("</");
            printFormat.document.write("script");
            printFormat.document.write(">");

            printFormat.document.write("</head><body onunload='afterprint()'><form  name='myForm' id='myForm' action='" + URL1 +"' method='POST' >");
            printFormat.document.write("<input type='hidden' name = 'printpdf' value='" + URL2 + "'>");
printFormat.document.write("</form>");
            printFormat.document.write("<");
            printFormat.document.write("script>submit(); ");
            printFormat.document.write("window.navigator.disablePACheck = false;print()");
            printFormat.document.write("</");
            printFormat.document.write("script");
            printFormat.document.write(">");

            printFormat.document.write("</body></html>");
            printFormat.document.close();



        }
```

**My java class**

```
public class PdfRH { public void doRequest(ControlBlock oSCB) throws Exception {
        HttpServletResponse response;


        response = oSCB.getHttpServletResponse();
        String pdfPath = oSCB.getRequestParameter("printpdf") ;
        System.out.println("*********************************************"+pdfPath);
        File pdf = new File(pdfPath);
        String pdfName = pdfPath.substring(pdfPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, pdfPath.length());
        ServletOutputStream stream = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf = null;

        try{
            stream = response.getOutputStream();
            //    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            response.setHeader("Content-type","application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=" + pdfName);  
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");

            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pdf);
           // response.setContentLength((int) pdf.length());
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            int readBytes = 0;
            /*pw.println("<html>");
            pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
            pw.println("<body>");
            pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
            pw.println("</body></html>");*/
            //response.getOutputStream().write(b);
            while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1)
                stream.write(readBytes);
        }
        catch(Exception ioe){
            throw new ServletException(ioe.getMessage());

        }
        finally 
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.close();
            if (buf != null)
                buf.close();
        }
    }
```

On a button click I am calling one `javascript` function and inside that javascript function I have written html coding where I have created a form and on submission I am passing the class name and one more variable i.e path of the pdf that will read a `pdf` and show it in popup window. 
As we can see that that whole control has gone to the java class but I want that on closing the `pdf` window I should reload the parent window

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code to your java class...

```
String code_windowClose = "<script>window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
</script>";
   stream.wrtie(code_windowClose);
```

This code will insert onunload event script onto your child window which is trying close the opener (i.e. parent) window.

Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: the method write is not applicable for the argument type String error is coming @pavan

Comment: try stream.write(code_windowClose.toByteArray())... it should work

Comment: pawan : i tried this method  but rather showing the pdf it is showing some ascii value in webpage

Comment: pawan@ one more thing i would like to add is how i can show the common title for each pdf i am showing on the webpage

Comment: @pawan this is working for me but the problem is : rather than showing a pdf on webpage it is showing
"%PDF-1.5 %µµµµ 1 0 obj <>>> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <>/Pattern<>/Font<>/XObject<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/Ibs/S/StructParents 0>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœ­T]kÛ@|è?ìã]¨Ï»÷-ÆIC71ô!ôA8Ži‰ej»”öõ_vO’[9²Ý>aä;öfvgFÃ œŸÇ£Û+À‹ ¸¼Á—œA•gÃ›‹Mž,~#zB»Wý|–gïó ®Ç#€õ˜´µd1MÊív¾ndobj 8 0 obj <> endobj 9 0 obj <> endobj 10 0 obj <> endobj 11 0ñ¹ c"Þ\5ÆhYcPPVAPÑ÷¸F£ˆˆš˜šèU÷“•¢»§ša°~§‡3ýUuuuý